# Transform.orient function in python Math3D ver 4.0.0

Tags: python, math3d

In python math3d version 4.0.0 which function correspond to the transform.orient function in version 3.4.1?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/morlin/pymath3d

Comment: According to the [source code](https://gitlab.com/morlin/pymath3d/-/blob/4.0-dev/math3d/transform.py?ref_type=heads#L149), it has the line `orientation = orient = ori = o = property(get_orientation, set_orientation)`. Is `orient` not working?